# AppleScript : keep word only from list

Tags: list, applescript

How can I only keep words / numbers from list?
I use the follow script and I want to count unique payment methods, but I have unwanted values on my list

I also tried to use "word of item" but this is not working

I try different version of the script but always having an issue

```
 set PaymentMethods to {}
    set UniquePaymentMethods to {}
    set walletPayement to {}
    set mobilePayemnt to {}

     tell application "Safari"
        set PaymentMethods to do JavaScript "var outPut=[]; var arr=document.getElementsByClassName('sortable Summary');for (var i in arr) {outPut.push(arr[i].innerHTML)};outPut;" in current tab of window 1
    end tell

   repeat with x from 1 to count of items of PaymentMethods
        set n to item x of PaymentMethods
        if n is in PaymentMethods and n is not in UniquePaymentMethods and n does not contain "<a href=\"/finance/Support.ok" and n does not contain "Safari" and n does not contain "None" then set end of UniquePaymentMethods to n
    end repeat
```

e.g of the result :

```
{"

                                    PayPal

                            ", "

                                    MasterCard (999)

                            ", "

                                    MasterCard (888)

                            ", application "Safari"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that you're generally mindful about supplying a sample of the input, as you've done here with the list that I presume relates to `PaymentMethods`.  But don't forget to also provide the output you want to get back at the end.  It took me a while to realise "keep words / numbers from list" was *actually* referring to items of class `text` (or `string`), which was about my fifth interpretation of what was being asked.

Your solution *appears* to do what you want, but it doesn't really because you've had to use that very case-specific set of conditionals, i.e.:

```
if n is in PaymentMethods ¬
    and n is not in UniquePaymentMethods ¬
   and n does not contain ("<a href=\"/finance/Support.ok") ¬
   and n does not contain ("Safari") ¬
   and n does not contain "None" then ¬
       set end of UniquePaymentMethods to n
```

Without that, the item `application "Safari"`, for instance, would simply be coerced into class `text`, which would return `"Safari"` in your resulting list.

So, while your request was to filter a list's data types to contain only `text` class items, your proposed fix, i.e.:

```
set n to item x of PaymentMethods as text
```

doesn't isolate `text` items; it coerces items of any class into `text`.

The way to filter a list by class type is to use this syntax:

```
get every [class] in [list]
```

where `[class]` is the AppleScript class you want to keep (discarding any items not of this class), and `[list]` is the list (or variable that references a list), e.g.:

```
every text in {1, "Hello", true, missing value, "2", text, number, pi}
    --> {"Hello", "2"}

every number in {1, "Hello", true, missing value, "2", text, number, pi}
    --> {1, 3.14159265359}

every application in {"PayPal", "MasterCard (999)", "MasterCard (888)", application "Safari"}
   --> {application "Safari"}

every text in {"PayPal", "MasterCard (999)", "MasterCard (888)", application "Safari"}
    --> {"PayPal", "MasterCard (999)", "MasterCard (888)"}
```

---

But, there's a lot you can do to simplify your script by having the initial JavaScript code do the heavy lifting so it returns a cleaner list of items that will be simpler for AppleScript to process, or eliminate any need for additional processing.

1. Your list items have a lot of whitespace in them.  In JS, use `trim()`.
2. Your AppleScript conditionals reference "innerHTML property without ever wanting to use any actual HTML.  You've been consistently interested only in the text that gets printed on your webpage.  Therefore, in JS, experiment with `innerText` applied to the right HTML element and you'll probably be able to isolate the payment methods text straight away.
3. You appear to want your list to contain unique items.  In JS, use sets, which are basically arrays with unique items.

Implementing these three recommendations, together with the above method of filtering by `text` class, would look something like:

```
tell application "Safari" to tell document 1 to tell (do JavaScript "
    [...new Set( document.getElementsByClassName('sortable Summary') )]
    .map( x => x.innerText.trim() );") ¬
    to set PaymentMethods to every text
```

As I don't know what your webpage source looks like, you may need to make slight adjustments to how you want to transform `innerText` besides `trim()`, and/or consider whether `getElementsByClassName('sortable Summary')` is the best way to get access to the parts of the HTML DOM tree you require.  `querySelectorAll()` is a much more powerful method to use, which I have mentioned before.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I missed your answer

Answer (score 0):

Found it, need to add the kind for each item

```
    set n to item x of PaymentMethods as text
```